# Expected Conditions

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How does the below code work, can someone explain line by line. I know what it does, but I don't understand how it works.

```
public boolean find(final By element, int timeout) {
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
            return wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    if (driver.findElement(element).isDisplayed()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Do you know what variables are? Do you know what a method is? Which part do you need help with?

Comment: I need help with what's inside the return statement. I know the basics of Java and have intermediate knowledge.